# Append vector to another with a move (pre C++11)

Tags: c++, move, stdvector

I'm handling some relatively large vectors of ints, and I have one top level vector that I need to accumulate the results of other (temporary) vectors into.

Extending it in place is sadly not an option as I receive the temporary vectors pre-cooked from another API, and I'm stuck with GCC 4.1.2 for the same reason, so none of the nice move semantics or std::move of C++11.

Currently I'm copying with insert, something like:

```
vector<int> accumulator;
for(){
    vector<int> tempVector = vectReturningFunction();
    ...
    if(!tempVector.empty()){
        accumulator.insert(accumulator.end(), tempVector.begin(), tempVector.end());
    }
}
```

As temp is routinely disposable and the data can be large enough I'd like to be able to move instead of copying, but I can't quite figure out an elegant way to do it.

Any solutions or even just pointers (no pun intended) in a useful direction would be hugely appreciated.
I also have a vague memory of reading a recipe by Stroustrup pre C++11, years ago, to move across STL containers, but there's so much C++11 stuff around these days no amount of searching served.

Thanks.

Comment: appending a `std::vector` is a re-allocation anyway, even with C++11 (unless the vector to be appended had enough capacity). You can avoid the re-allocation by using `std::deque` instead, but you will have to copy the objects, I'm afraid (perhaps in C++11 you could avoid it).

Comment: You can take a const reference to an object returned by a function call, it will prevent copying the vector in `tempVector` (http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You couldn't move vector content in C++11 either. Move semantics would only work for the elements of the vector, but as the elements are `int` there is no benefit. What you want is just not possible. But if you want to avoid merging, you can store a vector of vectors:

```
vector< vector<int> > accumulator;
accumulator.reserve(expectedCount); // reserve some space so that you avoid copying contents on vector resizing.
for(/*...*/){
    accumulator.resize(accumulator.size()+1); // make space for a new vector
    vectReturningFunction().swap(accumulator.back()); // just swap no copy of the vector
}
```

It all depends on what you want to do with the accumulator. If you really need to have a single `vector<int>`, then it may still be cheaper to merge the vectors at the end rather than appending them one by one.

Comment: Flattening a vector of vectors at the end of the run has been the first port of call. It more or less came down to the same performance as far as what I care in actual use concerns me.

My situation is actually liveable as is, I was hoping to spare some memory on the way and/or find out some obscure corner of the language.

Could you elaborate on the no benefit part, please? I only have a vague idea of why that might be the case, so any direction to get further education would be great.

Many thanks.

Comment: @ThE_JacO: By no benefit I meant that moving a single `int` is the same as copying it. When appending a vector move semantics are beneficial only if the element type is movable (string, vector, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware appending in this and other cases will tend to present the same memory overhead regardless of C++ version. My question was more in the hope of a recipe of sorts that would get to the same results through other means. High hopes, but was worth a shot.
Thanks a lot again. At least knowing it's simply an impossibility I can focus on something else and let this one be.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that avoids copying the data (and re-allocation), in particular w/o C++11, is to accumulate into a `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> accumulator;
for(){
    // C++03
    accumulator.resize(accumulator.size()+1);
    vectReturningFunction().swap(accumulator.back()); // Juraj
    if(accumulator.back().empty())
        accumulator.resize(accumulator.size()-1);
    // C++11
    // auto temp = vectReturningFunction();
    // if(!temp.empty())
    //     accumulator.push_back(std::move(temp));
}
```

Comment: I do swap on the first batch (which is usually the largest), and I have explored a few options with vector of vectors and some (horrifying) C-Style arrays.
Ultimately it didn't net me a lot though as I'm literally stuck between two APIs so I get a one dimensional vector of ints, and I have to provide the same. It's kind of a limiting situation.
Thanks a lot.